# Best way to resolve the incompatibility between Overleaf and Texlive

Tags: texlive, circuitikz

I am using both Overleaf and Texlive.

The code using

`\ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.55, inductors/scale=0.55, blocks/scale=0.5, grounds/scale=0.55}`

works in Overleaf but fails in the latest version of Texlive.

Is `\usepackage{circuitikz-1.2.2}` the best way to resolve this issue or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: check which version you have in both sites, printing `\pgfcircversion` somewhere in the document. That code should not fail in recent `circuitikz`, so it can be a bug. Please add a MWE.

Comment: While adding the MWE, add the [tag:overleaf] tag, so they'll take a look.

Comment: Ping? Any news on this?

Answer (score 1):

Run this code (or without the `\ctikzset` if it fails).

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{resistors/scale=0.55, inductors/scale=0.55, blocks/scale=0.5, grounds/scale=0.55}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[R] ++(1,0)
    node[right]{Version is \pgfcircversion{} on Ti\emph{k}Z \pgfversion};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

In my machine, the output is:

[image]

while on overleaf with TeXLive2020 is:

[image]

and with TeXLive 2019:

[image]

...but the three examples work ok. Add to your question the relevant versions and show a minimal example that is failing, please!